# ¿Cómo puedo usar el método .sort() en un array dentro de un array?

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un array:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRpJW.png): [image: Aquí el array:]

Yo quiero ordenar todos los elementos de la pos 0

```
list[i][0]
```

Con el método sort intente esto:

```
list.sort(function (a, b) { return b[1][0] - a[1][0]; });
list.sort(function(a, b){return b.list-a.list});
list.sort(function (a, b) { return b[1][0] - a[1][0]; });
```

Pero ninguno funciona, como puedo lo podria ordenar?

Answer (score 0):

Ostia! Lo he resuelto. Vi un video de youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9v4dfxwlbQ&ab_channel=AlejandroAmador

Lo recomiendo!

Como yo solo necesito los 5 primeros, esto me va ayudar mucho, pero si tu necesitas todo, no se si te servira, pero aca esta el codigo:

```
list.sort(function(a, b){if(a>b){return 1}; if(a<b){return -1;} return 0;});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ojala les sirva!!